# 500 Internal Server Error - PHPMailer

Tags: php

I'm trying to include my class.phpmailer.php file but for some reason whenever I add my `require_once` code, my whole page breaks and gives me a 500 Internal Server error. My func.php script is located in `coupons/inc/` on my ftp server and my class.phpmailer.php file is in the same place.

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/busaweb/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
include('Mail.php');
include('Mail/mime.php');
require_once(ROOT_PATH . "/coupon/inc/class.phpmailer.php");
```

Is there something wrong with my .htaccess or am I not using the correct file path? Thank you.

Comment: a 500 error is just a generic server error to say "something is wrong". By default, it doesn't give you any idea what the issue is. To get specifics on what is wrong, you need to check your server error logs which typically reside at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: What is the error that breaks your website? Is it caused by the .htaccess (in that case you should edit that into your question) or is it caused by `class.phpmailer.php` not existing, ROOT_PATH being somewhere else, etc.

Comment: seen here: http://i.imgur.com/yrOvLHS.jpg (I thought root_path was the start of my ftp server and then I just included the folder paths to get to where my .php file really is). Both my php files exist in /coupon/inc

Comment: Start by keeping it simple and following an example provided by the guys that write phpMailer. [Radical idea... Read The Manual](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail)

Comment: Try to remove the colon at end of the busaweb file `ini_set("include_path", '/home/busaweb/php:'`

Comment: @e-Learner, the colon is used to separate directories in the include_path (to allow for more than one include path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the include file is in the same directory just use the following:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/class.phpmailer.php");
```